# Why are css files named with random numbers and letters?

Tags: css, drupal

I am working on a drupal site locally. When I inspect the LIVE version of the site, the css file names are random names with letters and numbers like 
css_Ogaf452VDr2oEkwk7Oe68.css.
I think this is a minification result of the original css files but is there any way to tell what the developer used to minify the code and why the random names?

Comment: It is because you have the option in Drupal to have Cached CSS and Cached JS.

Comment: To add onto @dippas comment, you can disable this by going to Admin -> Config -> Performance -> Aggregate and compress CSS files. Then, clear your cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the CSS is **aggregated**. The same can happen for JS.
The settings are here:
/admin/config/development/performance

If it is enabled, basically it will combine CSS and JS and put them into files like you mentioned.

Generally this will be enabled on production to assist with caching and disabled on development so get a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the explanation given by drupal itself

> Aggregates and optimizes CSS files into a cache file in the files
>   directory.
>
> The file name for the CSS cache file is generated from the hash of the
>   aggregated contents of the files in $css. This forces proxies and
>   browsers to download new CSS when the CSS changes.
>
> The cache file name is retrieved on a page load via a lookup variable
>   that contains an associative array. The array key is the hash of the
>   file names in $css while the value is the cache file name. The cache
>   file is generated in two cases. First, if there is no file name value
>   for the key, which will happen if a new file name has been added to
>   $css or after the lookup variable is emptied to force a rebuild of the
>   cache. Second, the cache file is generated if it is missing on disk.
>   Old cache files are not deleted immediately when the lookup variable
>   is emptied, but are deleted after a set period by
>   drupal_delete_file_if_stale(). This ensures that files referenced by a
>   cached page will still be available.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is cached. When you make a change to one of your style sheets it's not gong to be immediately displayed due to it being cached. Yo remedy this [clear your cache](https://www.drupal.org/node/337176).

Comment: And that explains the random file names?

Comment: Yes. It's how Drupal names the cached version of files.